Not being able to append table headers from a scraped page
I'm trying to scrape this page of peruvian teams. I'm able to extract the information that has multiple tables and a header which says the region of each team (that is in a table).
My problem is when I try to organize the data. I have multiple tables. What I want is to store the header of each table as a another column and get one whole dataset.
I share my code below:
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# This scrapper was made to retrieve all teams in peru from Wikiepdia.

url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Clubes_de_fútbol_del_Perú"

dfs = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "table"
        and tag.select_one('th:-soup-contains("Equipo", "Ciudad", "Fundación", "Estadio", "Liga")'))

for table in tables:
    for tag in table.select('[style="display:none"]'):
        tag.extract()
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df['Region'] = table.find_previous(["h3","h2"]).span.text
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
print(dfs)


#df.to_csv("/Users/home/Downloads/data_results_manager.csv", index=False)




I think my problem is when I append it and with the the second loop. This one.
 for tag in table.select('[style="display:none"]'):
        tag.extract()
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

Any help fixing my code will be greatly appreciate it.

Rather than web scraping, have you looked at just using Wikipedia's API and a Python API client like this one: https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/ This gets you directly to the wikitext. You can then use another Python package to extract structures like the table you're asking about. https://pypi.org/project/wikitextparser/0.7.3/

Well, I got a solution:
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import quote

# URL de la página
url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Clubes_de_fútbol_del_Perú"

# Codificar la URL
url_codificada = quote(url, safe=':/')

try:
    tablas = pd.read_html(url_codificada)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Ocurrió un error: {e}")

clean_tables :list[pd.DataFrame] = []
for table in tablas:
    tag = list(table.columns)[0]
    if tag not in ('Equipo', 'Club'):
        region = tag
    if any(item in ['Equipo', 'Ciudad', 'Fundación', 'Estadio', 'Liga'] for item in list(table.columns)):
        print(f'Exportando tabla: {region}')
        table['region'] = region
        clean_tables.append(table)
        table.to_csv(f"any_root\\table_{region}.csv", index=False)




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
